# min value of two decision variables

Tags: c, variables, constraints, minimum, cplex

I am trying to solve a MIP problem using C with Cplex linker. I need to find min value of two decision variables, as far as I know, I should write as a constraint because they are decision variables. `if` statement does not work for decision variables. Here is some part of my model in C.

```
void TSPMIP(int Scenario, int Agency)
{
    int i,j;
    double tmpDouble;

    IloEnv env; //Intialize the Cplex Environment
    try{
        IloModel model(env);
        D2Array Q_bar(env,Scenario);
        for(i=0;i<Scenario;i++)
        {
            Q_bar[i] = IloNumVarArray(env,Agency,0,IloInfinity,ILOINT);
        }
        IloNumVarArray Q(env,Agency,0,IloInfinity,ILOINT);   //definition of decision variables.
```

What I want to do is

```
for(i=0;i<Scenario;i++){
    for (j=0;j<Agency;j++){
        IloExpr v9(env);
        if (Q_bar[i][j]>=Q[j]){
            v9=min-Q_bar[i][j];
        }else {
            v9=min-Q[[j];
        }
        cons.add(v9==0);
        v9.end();
    }
}
model.add(cons);
```

But it does not work for decision variables.

Comment: This is C++ not C.. What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to model this is to add another variable and add constraints to enforce that the new variable must be smaller than each of the other variables.